# How to prevent autoimplementation of Sync

Tags: multithreading, struct, rust, traits, unsafe

I have a struct containing unsafe code with the following method:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<T> {
    items: Vec<Box<(T, String)>>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn add_element(&self, element: T, key: String) {
        if !(self.items.iter().any( |i| i.1 == key)) {
            let mut items = unsafe {change_mut(&(self.items))};
            items.push(Box::new((element,key)));
        }
    }
}

unsafe fn change_mut<T>(x: &T) -> &mut T { // changes &self to &mut self
    &mut *(x as *const T as *mut T)
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Arc::new(Foo { items: vec!() });
    let clone = foo.clone();

    // This should not be possible, as it might lead to UB
    thread::spawn(move || clone.add_element(1, String::from("one")));

    println!("{:?}", *foo);

}
```

This struct is completely safe until someone starts using this method while multithreading. However, due to the fact the struct only contains a `Vec<Box<T,String>>`, `Sync`is implemented by default, which I would like to prevent.

I have found two ways to do this, both of which are not that great...

1. Add a struct field which does not implement `Sync` for example `*const u8`, this is obviously rather bad, as it ends up resulting in unnecessary and unclear code and does not clearly show my intent.
2. `impl !Sync for Struct {}` is not available on stable and will be removed according to [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/13231).
   The corresponding error is telling me to use marker types instead, but [the documention](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) does not present a way to solve my problem either.

---

```
error: negative trait bounds are not yet fully implemented; use marker types for
 now (see issue #13231)
  --> src\holder.rs:44:1
   |
44 | impl !Sync for Struct {}
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please attempt to provide a [MCVE], ideally as a link to the playground. It is much easier to test the correctness of a solution when one does not have to *guess* at what is omitted.

Comment: (Example of MCVE: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bcfd5e96cfcd390de67bc738bd821108&version=stable)

Comment: No, your code isn't completely safe even with a single thread. It is UB to cast an &T to a &mut T. You should use UnsafeCell for this, which should also fix your Sync issue.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 you might want to chime in on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171420/unsafe-collection-which-allows-immutable-access-while-also-allowing-push then :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interior mutability in Rust **requires**<sup>1</sup> the use of [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) as a hint to the compiler that the normal rules **do not apply**.

Your structure should therefore look such:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<T> {
    items: UnsafeCell<Vec<Box<(T, String)>>>,
}
```

And then, the implementation of `add_element` is adjusted to:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn add_element(&self, element: T, key: String) {
        if !(self.items.iter().any( |i| i.1 == key)) {
            let mut items = unsafe { &mut *self.items.get() };
            //                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            items.push(Box::new((element,key)));
        }
    }
}
```

The use of `UnsafeCell` makes `change_mut` completely unnecessary: it is the purpose of `UnsafeCell`, after all, to allow interior mutability. Note how its `get` method returns a raw pointer, which cannot be dereferenced without an `unsafe` block.

---

Since `UnsafeCell` does not implement `Sync`, `Foo<T>` will not implement `Sync` either, and therefore it becomes unnecessary to use negative implementations or any marker.

---

<sup>1</sup> *If you do not use it directly, chances are the abstractions you do use are built on it. It is as special as it could be: it is a lang item, as denoted by its attribute `#[lang = "unsafe_cell"]`.*